# OpenCV, SIFT : All of the features of 2 different insects are matching

Tags: opencv, sift, random-forest, feature-extraction

I wan to create a classifier in order to identify an insect by its captured image. At the first time, I used HuMomemnts but images captured in different resolutions gave incorrect results since HuMoments are scale variant. After doing some search on the internet, I found that usage SIFT and SURF can solve my problem and thus, I tried to see what happens when I use SIFT. The first two images below belongs to to different insect kind. The results was bizarre since all features out of 400 were matching (see 3rd image).

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
int main()
{
Mat src = imread(firstInsect);
Mat src2 = imread("secondInsect");

if(src.empty() || src2.empty())
{
    printf("Can not read one of the image\n");
    return -1;
}

//Detect key point in the image
SiftFeatureDetector detector(400);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(src, keypoints);

//cout << keypoints.size() << " of keypoints are found" << endl;

cv::FileStorage fs(firstInsectXML, FileStorage::WRITE);
detector.write(fs);
fs.release();


SiftFeatureDetector detector2(400);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints2;
detector.detect(src2, keypoints2);

cv::FileStorage fs2(secondInsectXML,  FileStorage::WRITE);
detector.write(fs2);
fs2.release();


//Compute the SIFT feature descriptors for the keypoints
//Multiple features can be extracted from a single keypoint, so the result is a
//matrix where row "i" is the list of features for keypoint "i"

SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors;
extractor.compute(src, keypoints, descriptors);

SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor2;
Mat descriptors2;
extractor.compute(src2, keypoints2, descriptors2);


//Print some statistics on the matrices returned
//Size size = descriptors.size();
//cout<<"Query descriptors height: "<<size.height<< " width: "<<size.width<< " area: "<<size.area() << " non-zero: "<<countNonZero(descriptors)<<endl;



//saveKeypoints(keypoints, detector);


Mat output;
drawKeypoints(src, keypoints, output, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
imwrite(firstInsectPicture, output);

Mat output2;
drawKeypoints(src2, keypoints2, output2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
imwrite(secondInsectPicture, output2); 


//Corresponded points
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors, descriptors2, matches);

cout<< "Number of matches: "<<matches.size()<<endl;

Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(src, keypoints, src2, keypoints2, matches, img_matches);
imwrite(resultPicture, img_matches); 

system("PAUSE");
waitKey(10000);

return 0;}
```

Question 1: Why all of the features are matching in these two images?

Question 2: How can I store(i.e. XML file) features of an image in a way that the features can be stored in order to train them in a classification tree (i.e. random tree)?

Answer (score 2):

SIFT essential takes a training image and extract points of interest. These points are filtered and low contrast points are discarded. High contrast points after some computation are used to describe a object or scene. These essentially ROIs can be used to identify similar patches even when uniform scale, orientation etc. changes.

We have several problems here. Firstly, you use SIFT for non-rigid surface registration purposes. This means you try to classify different bugs (in-group) by their common features, but actually it was never indended for this purpose. Also, the bugs are actually quite different and seem to  have rather little in common. Secondly, you utilize SIFT with a very low quality input source (low quality feature points) which is essentially only a binary mask.

If you experiment with different methods for object registration it is probably a good idea to utilize a [well known and widely used toy dataset](http://www.lems.brown.edu/vision/researchAreas/SIID/) first as it simplifies your problem and allows you to see what works on easy cases and what doesn't after which you go back to your real dataset.

There are many interesting methods which seem more [suitable](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~kon/publication/KFujiwara_ICCV11_preprint.pdf) for in-group registration.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [Shape Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context) given that you have binary images with fairly clear boundaries.